# ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

Code:

```
h1=df[df["native-country"]!="?"]
f1=h1.mode()
df['native-country'] = df['native-country'].replace("?",df['native-country'].mode())
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace
```

I dont know why im getting this error hope someone could help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My simplistic, recommended answer is to use:

```
mode = df[df["native-country"]!="?"]["native-country"].mode()[0]
df['native-country'] = df['native-country'].replace("?", mode)
```

but this comes with a major caveat and further explanation below.

---

**More detailed explanation:**

`df['native-country'].mode()` will return a Series, not an individual value.  This is because there can be more than one mode.  Consider the following:

```
d = {'native-country': ['?', None, 'Spain', 'Germany', 'Greece']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
mode = df['native-country'].mode()
```

Inspecting `mode` reveals that there are actually multiple mode values, since the most common element of the Series is any element that occurs once:

```
0          ?
1    Germany
2     Greece
3      Spain
dtype: object
```

It's also worth noting that the `None` value is excluded by default.  Even in the case where there is a single most common value, `Series.mode()` returns a single element Series:

```
d = {'native-country': ['?', None, 'Spain', 'Germany', 'Spain']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
mode = df['native-country'].mode()
```

This gives `mode` as:

```
0    Spain
dtype: object
```

My very simplistic approach just uses the first value of the returned Series as the value used to replace, but you'll have to decide for yourself if you want a more complex logic for the case where there may be multiple modes.

---

**Full, copy-pasteable code example:**

```
import pandas as pd


d = {'native-country': ['?', None, 'Spain', 'Germany', 'Spain']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

mode = df[df["native-country"]!="?"]["native-country"].mode()[0]
df['native-country'] = df['native-country'].replace("?", mode)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add squared brackets, as follows

```
.replace(["?"],mode)
```